# Existence of weak limit for bouded sequence $\{y_n\}$ such that for every weak limit point $\{y_n\}$ must equal $y$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, sequences-and-series

Let $X$ be separable Banach space and $\{x_n\}$ be a bounded sequence, relatively weakly compact sequence in $X$. we set $y_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i}$, then (together with the Krein and Eberlein-Smulian theorems), we can assume that there exists a **subsequence** of $\{y_n\}$ converges weakly to some element $y \in X$.

We suppose that  every **weak limit** point of $\{y_n\}$ must equal $y$.

Can we say that $\{y_n\}$ must converge weakly to $y$?

Comment: What does it mean for a sequence to *equal* a single element?  It sounds like you're asking if the sequence must be constant, but that clearly isn't right.  Is there a typo?

Comment: Also the title doesn't make grammatical sense.

Comment: Are you asking if the sequence $y_n$ must converge (weakly?) to $y$?

Comment: @NateEldredge see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y_n$ does not converge weakly to $y$ then there is a weakly open neighborhood $U$ of $y$ and a subsequence $y_{n_k} \notin U$.  By weak compactness this subsequence has a weak limit point $z \notin U$.  But $z$ is then also a weak limit point of the original sequence $y_n$, contradicting uniqueness.

Comment: If $ \{y_n \} $ is relatively weakly compact, then $ \{y_ {n_k} \} $ is a convergent sequence?

Comment: @KarimKHAN: The subsequence $y_{n_k}$ in my answer isn't necessarily convergent, though it would be possible to find a further subsequence of it which is.